# Reference to object

Tags: c++, reference

Let we have declaration:

```
...
int a= 5;
int& b= a;
...
```

I dont understand, what difference between `a` and `b`. I think, that `a` and `b` is just adress. But where is this adress in memory? So, let we define a function:

```
int foo(int& x)
{
    return x;
}
...
foo(a);
foo(b);
```

What is occuring when `foo` is calling? I.e. when we'r returning a value we'r going by adress whos in `a` or `b`?

Comment: `b` is just another name for `a`. Just think of it as an alias. Anything you do with `b`, you really do with `a`. As for the function, it is `void` so it makes no sense to return anything.

Comment: What? Also, you can't return something from a `void` function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c). See also [What value does a reference store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412084/what-value-does-a-reference-variable-in-c-store)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens in your code is that `a` and `b` are effectively aliases for the same memory location.

Thus

```
foo(a);
```

and

```
foo(b);
```

are in effect identical.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Read up for more information, things are usually very well detailed in cplusplus.com articles

Comment: -1:  There are no pointers here, and cplusplus.com is a stinking pile.

Comment: @JohnDibling In a sense, there actually are pointers here. First, the OP talks about addresses and second, references are basically nice pointers. Your opinion on `cplusplus.com` is irrelevant here, if you don't specifically target `http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/`.

Comment: @stefan:  The linked page on cplusplus.com says that pointers and arrays are the same thing.  That's wrong.  I'm sure I could find more errors on that specific page, but I disagree that my observation that cplusplus.com is a poor resource is ever irrelevant.  With many errors sprinkled throughout the site, my feeling is it just can't be trusted as a resource at all.  Especially by newbies, who simply won't know the difference between good information and bad information.  How could they?

Comment: The link actually discusses both pointers and references

Comment: @JohnDibling Concerning this very bad mistake: It's irrelevant. Neither a pointer nor a plain array should be used, especially not by a beginner. But why cursing ("stinking pile") if you could just _tell them_? Waste of time? Alternatively you could have also just pointed out a better resource: cppreference.com

Comment: I don't see how its wrong in saying that the variable when you define an array is similar to a pointer. An array will always point to the space in memory where it is stored so it acts as a constant pointer.
If you disagree with this could you explain your reasoning?